# Not able to align ion-avatar to the center of <ion-item> in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 project and I have added the ion-avatar but it is not coming in the center of the

This is my **editprofile.page.html**:

```
<ion-item class="newitem2">
    <ion-avatar>
        <img name="profile_pic" [src]="this.userdetailsedit.value.profile_pic"/>
    </ion-avatar>   
</ion-item>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please add class on ion-avatar

your html file looks like

```
<ion-item class="newitem2">
    <ion-avatar class="image-center">
        <img name="profile_pic" [src]="this.userdetailsedit.value.profile_pic"/>
    </ion-avatar>   
</ion-item>
```

add this scss

```
.image-center{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It Worked.